# Learning shell scripts

Tags: linux

I am trying to teach myself to write Shell Scripts on my Raspberry Pi, but I am struggling to make a menu where a user can choose from these different options:

•display a list of current users
•display a list of all files including hidden files in the home directory
•output a calendar for the current month
•quit the script.

I am aware that some kind of loop is also needed, any suggestions guys?

Comment: Teach yourself? This sounds *a lot* like homework...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an excellent tool for managing dialogs named **dialog** ;). I don't know is it installed on your raspberry but it can be surely compiled for.
Here is an article about it's features with examples:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807